# Batch Gradient Descent algorithm I made based on CS229 Lec2 by Andrew Ng is giving unexpected results

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

So I started learning ML yesterday and I saw two lectures of CS229 of Stanford Uni's youtube channel (Instructor is Andrew Ng). I tried implementing the "**Batch Gradient Descent algorithm**" he explained in Lecture 2 in python.

This is the code I implemented:

```
def hypothesis(X: list, parameters: list) -> float:
    result = 0
    # The first elemetn of X is always 1.
    for i in range(0, len(X)):
        result += X[i] * parameters[i]
    return result

# This returns a list of Parameters.
# It accepts only 1 feature for now. 
# So dataset is just a list of [[1, 1, ...], [x1, x2, ...], [y1, y2, ...]]
def batch_gradient_descent(dataset: list) -> list[float]:
    learning_rate = 0.001
    m = len(dataset[0])
    n = len(dataset) - 1
    parameters = [0.0] * (n+1)
    steps = 100
    for k in range(0, steps):
        for j in range(0, n):
            gradient = 0
            for datapoint in range(0, m):
                h = hypothesis([ dataset[0][datapoint], dataset[1][datapoint] ], parameters)
                y = dataset[2][datapoint]
                gradient += (h - y) * dataset[j][datapoint]

            correction = learning_rate * gradient
            parameters[j] -= correction

    return parameters
```

Data I used:

```
--------------------
--------------------
Horsepower  Weight   
--------------------
130.0       3504.0   
165.0       3693.0   
150.0       3436.0   
150.0       3433.0   
140.0       3449.0   
198.0       4341.0   
220.0       4354.0   
215.0       4312.0   
225.0       4425.0   
190.0       3850.0   
115.0       3090.0   
165.0       4142.0   
153.0       4034.0   
175.0       4166.0   
175.0       3850.0   
170.0       3563.0   
160.0       3609.0   
140.0       3353.0   
150.0       3761.0   
225.0       3086.0   
95.0        2372.0   
95.0        2833.0   
97.0        2774.0   
85.0        2587.0   
88.0        2130.0   
46.0        1835.0   
87.0        2672.0   
90.0        2430.0   
95.0        2375.0   
113.0       2234.0   
90.0        2648.0   
215.0       4615.0   
200.0       4376.0   
210.0       4382.0   
193.0       4732.0   
88.0        2130.0   
90.0        2264.0   
95.0        2228.0   
0.0         2046.0   
48.0        1978.0   
100.0       2634.0   
105.0       3439.0   
100.0       3329.0   
88.0        3302.0   
100.0       3288.0   
165.0       4209.0   
175.0       4464.0   
153.0       4154.0   
150.0       4096.0   
180.0       4955.0   
170.0       4746.0   
175.0       5140.0   
110.0       2962.0   
72.0        2408.0   
100.0       3282.0   
88.0        3139.0   
86.0        2220.0   
90.0        2123.0   
70.0        2074.0   
76.0        2065.0   
65.0        1773.0   
69.0        1613.0   
60.0        1834.0   
70.0        1955.0   
95.0        2278.0   
80.0        2126.0   
54.0        2254.0   
90.0        2408.0   
86.0        2226.0   
165.0       4274.0   
175.0       4385.0   
150.0       4135.0   
153.0       4129.0   
150.0       3672.0   
208.0       4633.0   
155.0       4502.0   
160.0       4456.0   
190.0       4422.0   
97.0        2330.0   
150.0       3892.0   
130.0       4098.0   
140.0       4294.0   
150.0       4077.0   
112.0       2933.0   
76.0        2511.0   
87.0        2979.0   
69.0        2189.0   
86.0        2395.0   
92.0        2288.0   
97.0        2506.0   
80.0        2164.0   
88.0        2100.0   
175.0       4100.0   
150.0       3672.0   
145.0       3988.0   
137.0       4042.0   
150.0       3777.0   
198.0       4952.0   
150.0       4464.0   
158.0       4363.0   
150.0       4237.0   
215.0       4735.0   
225.0       4951.0   
175.0       3821.0   
105.0       3121.0   
100.0       3278.0   
100.0       2945.0   
88.0        3021.0   
95.0        2904.0   
46.0        1950.0   
150.0       4997.0   
167.0       4906.0   
170.0       4654.0   
180.0       4499.0   
100.0       2789.0   
88.0        2279.0   
72.0        2401.0   
94.0        2379.0   
90.0        2124.0   
85.0        2310.0   
107.0       2472.0   
90.0        2265.0   
145.0       4082.0   
230.0       4278.0   
49.0        1867.0   
75.0        2158.0   
91.0        2582.0   
112.0       2868.0   
150.0       3399.0   
110.0       2660.0   
122.0       2807.0   
180.0       3664.0   
95.0        3102.0   
0.0         2875.0   
100.0       2901.0   
100.0       3336.0   
67.0        1950.0   
80.0        2451.0   
65.0        1836.0   
75.0        2542.0   
100.0       3781.0   
110.0       3632.0   
105.0       3613.0   
140.0       4141.0   
150.0       4699.0   
150.0       4457.0   
140.0       4638.0   
150.0       4257.0   
83.0        2219.0   
67.0        1963.0   
78.0        2300.0   
52.0        1649.0   
61.0        2003.0   
75.0        2125.0   
75.0        2108.0   
75.0        2246.0   
97.0        2489.0   
93.0        2391.0   
67.0        2000.0   
95.0        3264.0   
105.0       3459.0   
72.0        3432.0   
72.0        3158.0   
170.0       4668.0   
145.0       4440.0   
150.0       4498.0   
148.0       4657.0   
110.0       3907.0   
105.0       3897.0   
110.0       3730.0   
95.0        3785.0   
110.0       3039.0   
110.0       3221.0   
129.0       3169.0   
75.0        2171.0   
83.0        2639.0   
100.0       2914.0   
78.0        2592.0   
96.0        2702.0   
71.0        2223.0   
97.0        2545.0   
97.0        2984.0   
70.0        1937.0   
90.0        3211.0   
95.0        2694.0   
88.0        2957.0   
98.0        2945.0   
115.0       2671.0   
53.0        1795.0   
86.0        2464.0   
81.0        2220.0   
92.0        2572.0   
79.0        2255.0   
83.0        2202.0   
140.0       4215.0   
150.0       4190.0   
120.0       3962.0   
152.0       4215.0   
100.0       3233.0   
105.0       3353.0   
81.0        3012.0   
90.0        3085.0   
52.0        2035.0   
60.0        2164.0   
70.0        1937.0   
53.0        1795.0   
100.0       3651.0   
78.0        3574.0   
110.0       3645.0   
95.0        3193.0   
71.0        1825.0   
70.0        1990.0   
75.0        2155.0   
72.0        2565.0   
102.0       3150.0   
150.0       3940.0   
88.0        3270.0   
108.0       2930.0   
120.0       3820.0   
180.0       4380.0   
145.0       4055.0   
130.0       3870.0   
150.0       3755.0   
68.0        2045.0   
80.0        2155.0   
58.0        1825.0   
96.0        2300.0   
70.0        1945.0   
145.0       3880.0   
110.0       4060.0   
145.0       4140.0   
130.0       4295.0   
110.0       3520.0   
105.0       3425.0   
100.0       3630.0   
98.0        3525.0   
180.0       4220.0   
170.0       4165.0   
190.0       4325.0   
149.0       4335.0   
78.0        1940.0   
88.0        2740.0   
75.0        2265.0   
89.0        2755.0   
63.0        2051.0   
83.0        2075.0   
67.0        1985.0   
78.0        2190.0   
97.0        2815.0   
110.0       2600.0   
110.0       2720.0   
48.0        1985.0   
66.0        1800.0   
52.0        1985.0   
70.0        2070.0   
60.0        1800.0   
110.0       3365.0   
140.0       3735.0   
139.0       3570.0   
105.0       3535.0   
95.0        3155.0   
85.0        2965.0   
88.0        2720.0   
100.0       3430.0   
90.0        3210.0   
105.0       3380.0   
85.0        3070.0   
110.0       3620.0   
120.0       3410.0   
145.0       3425.0   
165.0       3445.0   
139.0       3205.0   
140.0       4080.0   
68.0        2155.0   
95.0        2560.0   
97.0        2300.0   
75.0        2230.0   
95.0        2515.0   
105.0       2745.0   
85.0        2855.0   
97.0        2405.0   
103.0       2830.0   
125.0       3140.0   
115.0       2795.0   
133.0       3410.0   
71.0        1990.0   
68.0        2135.0   
115.0       3245.0   
85.0        2990.0   
88.0        2890.0   
90.0        3265.0   
110.0       3360.0   
130.0       3840.0   
129.0       3725.0   
138.0       3955.0   
135.0       3830.0   
155.0       4360.0   
142.0       4054.0   
125.0       3605.0   
150.0       3940.0   
71.0        1925.0   
65.0        1975.0   
80.0        1915.0   
80.0        2670.0   
77.0        3530.0   
125.0       3900.0   
71.0        3190.0   
90.0        3420.0   
70.0        2200.0   
70.0        2150.0   
65.0        2020.0   
69.0        2130.0   
90.0        2670.0   
115.0       2595.0   
115.0       2700.0   
90.0        2556.0   
76.0        2144.0   
60.0        1968.0   
70.0        2120.0   
65.0        2019.0   
90.0        2678.0   
88.0        2870.0   
90.0        3003.0   
90.0        3381.0   
78.0        2188.0   
90.0        2711.0   
75.0        2542.0   
92.0        2434.0   
75.0        2265.0   
65.0        2110.0   
105.0       2800.0   
65.0        2110.0   
48.0        2085.0   
48.0        2335.0   
67.0        2950.0   
67.0        3250.0   
67.0        1850.0   
0.0         1835.0   
67.0        2145.0   
62.0        1845.0   
132.0       2910.0   
100.0       2420.0   
88.0        2500.0   
0.0         2905.0   
72.0        2290.0   
84.0        2490.0   
84.0        2635.0   
92.0        2620.0   
110.0       2725.0   
84.0        2385.0   
58.0        1755.0   
64.0        1875.0   
60.0        1760.0   
67.0        2065.0   
65.0        1975.0   
62.0        2050.0   
68.0        1985.0   
63.0        2215.0   
65.0        2045.0   
65.0        2380.0   
74.0        2190.0   
0.0         2320.0   
75.0        2210.0   
75.0        2350.0   
100.0       2615.0   
74.0        2635.0   
80.0        3230.0   
110.0       2800.0   
76.0        3160.0   
116.0       2900.0   
120.0       2930.0   
110.0       3415.0   
105.0       3725.0   
88.0        3060.0   
85.0        3465.0   
88.0        2605.0   
88.0        2640.0   
88.0        2395.0   
85.0        2575.0   
84.0        2525.0   
90.0        2735.0   
92.0        2865.0   
0.0         3035.0   
74.0        1980.0   
68.0        2025.0   
68.0        1970.0   
63.0        2125.0   
70.0        2125.0   
88.0        2160.0   
75.0        2205.0   
70.0        2245.0   
67.0        1965.0   
67.0        1965.0   
67.0        1995.0   
110.0       2945.0   
85.0        3015.0   
92.0        2585.0   
112.0       2835.0   
96.0        2665.0   
84.0        2370.0   
90.0        2950.0   
86.0        2790.0   
52.0        2130.0   
84.0        2295.0   
79.0        2625.0   
82.0        2720.0   
--------------------
--------------------
```

[image]

I tried printing the parameters at every step. I got this:

```
1209.642 86076.14881399993 0.0
-3616110.5937508577 -279593819.19087416 0.0
11750020241.999323 908452640594.132 0.0
-38178010328859.69 -2951732368621751.0 0.0
1.2404748891214426e+17 9.590729980712882e+18 0.0
-4.0305346907089096e+20 -3.1162073682816065e+22 0.0
1.309596029349179e+24 1.0125139985862442e+26 0.0
-4.255122190216129e+27 -3.289847164113574e+29 0.0
1.3825687042337605e+31 1.0689328126167345e+33 0.0
-4.4922240454616045e+34 -3.473162432445682e+36 0.0
1.459607527121594e+38 1.1284953684434372e+40 0.0
-4.742537575307189e+41 -3.666692305264664e+43 0.0
1.5409390699399244e+45 1.1913768401222262e+47 0.0
-5.006798954278208e+48 -3.871005955808367e+50 0.0
1.626802529547047e+52 1.2577621626727734e+54 0.0
-5.285785377659914e+55 -4.0867042725097936e+57 0.0
1.7174504312126087e+59 1.327846575974226e+61 0.0
-5.580317347236328e+62 -4.3144216262158e+64 0.0
1.8131493712968694e+66 1.4018361989676038e+68 0.0
-5.89126108439398e+69 -4.554827735877949e+71 0.0
1.9141808013131666e+73 1.479948635853601e+75 0.0
-6.21953107768746e+76 -4.80862963820249e+78 0.0
2.0208418556796408e+80 1.562413616068679e+82 0.0
-6.566092772359206e+83 -5.076573767052118e+85 0.0
2.1334462255943383e+87 1.6494736699215312e+89 0.0
-6.931965409723172e+90 -5.359448148715279e+92 0.0
2.2523250816041576e+94 1.7413848418771075e+96 0.0
-7.318225024763566e+97 -5.658084719499105e+99 0.0
2.3778280475805906e+101 1.8384174435858807e+103 0.0
-7.726007610764286e+104 -5.9733617724621985e+106 0.0
2.5103242289669556e+108 1.94085684887302e+110 0.0
-8.156512460275961e+111 -6.306206540483137e+113 0.0
2.650203298321139e+115 2.049004333025595e+117 0.0
-8.611005692247278e+118 -6.657597923261204e+120 0.0
2.7978766413462646e+122 2.1631779588461343e+124 0.0
-9.090823975692992e+125 -7.028569366270097e+127 0.0
2.9537785667801504e+129 2.2837135120783844e+131 0.0
-9.597378460850402e+132 -7.420211900131045e+134 0.0
3.1183675837015125e+136 2.4109654889565067e+138 0.0
-1.0132158929386176e+140 -7.83367734934446e+141 0.0
3.2921277500095453e+143 2.545308138781879e+145 0.0
-1.0696738175858366e+147 -8.270181719817e+148 0.0
3.4755700960430374e+150 2.68713656459401e+152 0.0
-1.1292776633320997e+154 -8.7310087751468e+155 0.0
3.6692341275254375e+157 2.8368678851723386e+159 0.0
-1.192202725667313e+161 -9.21751381218474e+162 0.0
3.8736894122565677e+164 2.9949424617866774e+166 0.0
-1.2586340678117058e+168 -9.73112764697537e+169 0.0
4.089537255216881e+171 3.161825193303948e+173 0.0
-1.3287670649884894e+175 -1.0273360822801339e+177 0.0
4.317412467011484e+178 3.338006883460344e+180 0.0
-1.4028079790243477e+182 -1.0845808052705324e+184 0.0
4.557985230854093e+185 3.5240056843197724e+187 0.0
-1.4809745649674168e+189 -1.1450152909557031e+191 0.0
4.811963073582515e+192 3.7203686201642553e+194 0.0
-1.5634967115070683e+196 -1.2088172777457151e+198 0.0
5.080092946501931e+199 3.927673196297529e+201 0.0
-1.6506171170787165e+203 -1.2761744079041203e+205 0.0
5.3631634221758376e+206 4.146529097493836e+208 0.0
-1.742592003642309e+210 -1.3472847794056978e+212 0.0
5.662007013625794e+213 4.37757998108672e+215 0.0
-1.8396918702335722e+217 -1.422357528544507e+219 0.0
5.977502622760216e+220 4.6215053699715863e+222 0.0
-1.9422022885043654e+224 -1.5016134450057786e+226 0.0
6.310578125233412e+227 4.879022651089099e+229 0.0
-2.050424742591643e+231 -1.5852856212105161e+233 0.0
6.662213099337065e+234 5.150889185267103e+236 0.0
-2.1646775157852207e+238 -1.6736201378425563e+240 0.0
7.033441706949243e+241 5.437904534626251e+243 0.0
-2.2852966266020594e+245 -1.7668767875742764e+247 0.0
7.425355735014756e+248 5.740912814099934e+250 0.0
-2.41263681701997e+252 -1.8653298391193682e+254 0.0
7.839107806501123e+255 6.060805173984542e+257 0.0
-2.5470725957772215e+259 -1.969268843859789e+261 0.0
8.275914770273959e+262 6.398522420821118e+264 0.0
-2.688999339806387e+266 -2.0789994874191805e+268 0.0
8.737061279861211e+269 6.7550577843166214e+271 0.0
-2.838834457041781e+273 -2.1948444886872753e+275 0.0
9.223903571631758e+276 7.131459838442021e+278 0.0
-2.9970186140201774e+280 -2.3171445489392822e+282 0.0
9.737873453499758e+283 7.528835585298604e+285 0.0
-3.164017031885428e+287 -2.446259353841639e+289 0.0
1.0280482515885604e+291 7.948353710822016e+292 0.0
-3.340320854608377e+294 -2.5825686312910795e+296 0.0
1.0853326577318167e+298 8.391248021898751e+299 0.0
-3.526448593446011e+301 -2.7264732681980627e+303 0.0
1.14580903777524e+305 inf 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
nan nan 0.0
The final parameter list nan nan 0.0
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong. I tried using a learning rate of 0.00000001 for 10000 steps but the parameters just keep on increasing, though I don't get NaN.

Please help me figure out what is wrong.

[image]

This is what I followed (from the lecture notes)
If you have any tips or guidance please provide so, I just started yesterday so mistakes are only natural.

EDIT:
I lowered the learning rate and increased the steps as:

```
learning_rate = 0.0000001
steps = 10000
```

The *theta1* parameter decreases from *27* but very slowly and *theta0* grows continuously.
I plotted this and got:
[image]

Why does the learning rate needs to be so low? In the lecture prof. Andrew said a value of 0.01 or 0.1 would suffice.